# PHP redirect back to previous page

Tags: php, session, redirect, http-referer

What I have done for the login.php page is if a user has logged in, he will be redirected to first.php page.

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['usr']) && isset($_SESSION['pswd'])){
    header("Location: first.php");
}
```

In all other pages, if user hasn't logged in he will be redirected to login.php page.

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['usr']) || !isset($_SESSION['pswd'])){
    header("Location: login.php");
}
```

Here is the problem: is there a way to redirect the user back to where he was from? Say if you are trying to reach second.php while you are not logged in, you will be redirected to login.php page now; once you log in, can you be redirected back to second.php instead of first.php?

I have tried to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, but this variable doesn't contain anything; it only contain something if you are here because you have clicked a link.

Comment: you can attach previous page as parameter to login.php as `login.php?redir=previous` then on login page redirect to that page again after login

Comment: @Akam This is a pretty straight forward way to do make it work and your explanation is even easier to understand than codes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. On the page they try to login set a session variable containing the URL of that page.
2. Then redirect them to the login page.
3. After a successful login get the previous URL from their session and redirect them there.

Have the page that does the redirecting set a session variable that is the URL of that page:

```
session_start();
if (!$logged_in)
{
    $_SESSION['redirect_url'] = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit;
}
```

Then after a successful login redirect them to that URL:

```
session_start();

/* Login code goes here */

$redirect_url = (isset($_SESSION['redirect_url'])) ? $_SESSION['redirect_url'] : '/';
unset($_SESSION['redirect_url']);
header("Location: $redirect_url", true, 303);
exit;
```

The above can be improved upon but this should give you the idea.

Comment: This is the way I do it now. The only difference is unset($_SESSION['redirect_url']) can not kill my URL session variable so I use session_destroy() in my logout page in order to achieve the same thing. Thanks John.

Answer (score 2):

$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] depends on the Web Browser, not all browser sends the referrer back to the server. A better approach, used by many big sites, is passing on the current page to the login page:

```
header("Location: first.php?".$currentPageUrl);
```

The $currentPageUrl can be get from the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] or $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

Upon login you can redirect user to the $currentPageUrl again.

Apart from this, it does not sound right to store the user name and password in the $_SESSION, but this is a separate issue.

Comment: I tried this one and was almost there. If I hardcode the url then it will be fine. However neither $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] nor $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] works smoothly in my case as my pages are in a subdirectory, they will include the directory in their url. They can be addressed but needs additional changes. Thanks for that.